# matplotlib animation plotting all the points instead of just the latest iteration

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a set of points that move around in a 2D space using matplotlib. It currently sort of works in that it the code does produce an animation of the points but it isn't how I was thinking it would work. Instead of plotting the points at each moment in time it plots them at all points in time instead.

For example if the code is run with twenty points I would like it to show the twenty points at one frame and then those same points at the next frame and so on. Instead it keeps the previous frames points instead of just showing the new ones.

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Also, I've found from my research that it would be best to enable blitting for the animation to optimise the problem but when I add blit=True as an argument for the FuncAnimation the console spits out a huge traceback ending in :

File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1568, in _draw_frame
    a.set_animated(self._blit)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

I also don't know why this happens and searching online has not been helpful.

The code follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Import plotting library
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np #Import numpy library

dim = 2             #Defines the dimensionality of the system
n = 25               #Number of BOIDS
tmax = 80             #Length of sim
dmax = 5            #Distance boids can "see", determines what other boids interact with them
o = np.zeros(dim) #Origin as vector
r = np.random.rand(n,dim) #Places BOIDs randomly with co-ordinates (x,y,z) from 0 to 1. Has dimensions n and dim
v = 2*np.random.rand(n,dim)-1#Sets initial velocity of each BOID from -1 to 1 in each cardinal direction
rt = np.zeros((tmax,n,dim)) #This array contains the whole system's positions at each point in time
x = np.empty(n)
y = np.empty(n)
d = np.zeros(n)
vk = np.zeros((n,2))
vksum = np.zeros((n,2))
pltx = np.zeros((tmax,n))
plty = np.zeros((tmax,n))
"""rt[a][b][0] is the x co-ordinate of boid n=b at t=a
   rt[a][b][1] is the y co-ordiante of boid n=b at t=a
   np.linalg.norm gives the modulus of an array, check documentation for arguments"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,9))
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75') #Sets up a grid on subplot
ax.set_xlim(-50,50)
ax.set_ylim(-50,50) #Set limits for x and y axes 

for t in range (0,tmax):
    for i in range (0,n):
        for k in range (0,n):
            if abs(k-n)>0:
                d[k] = ((r[i][0]-r[k][0])**2+(r[i][1]-r[k][1])**2)**(1/2) #Checks distance from ith boid to each other boid
            if (d[k]-dmax)<0:   #If they are within range of the ith boid
                vk[k] = (v[i] +v[k])/((np.linalg.norm(v[i]))*np.linalg.norm(v[k]))#Aligns the velocity of ith boid toward the velocity of the kth boid
        for l in range (0,n):
            vksum[i] = vksum[i] + vk[l] #Sums the boid's velocity contributions together
        v[i] = (3/4)*v[i] + (vksum[i]/np.linalg.norm(vksum[i])) #Sets the boid's new velocity 
        r[i] = r[i] + v[i]  #Sets the boid's new position
        rt[t][i] = r[i] #Logs the position of the boid in the time array
        pltx[t][i] = r[i][0]
        plty[t][i] = r[i][1]


def init():
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[0][i][0]
        y[i] = rt[0][i][1]
    return x,y,  

def update(j):
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[j][i][0]
        y[i] = rt[j][i][1]
    points = ax.scatter(x[:],y[:],c='r')
    return x,y

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=tmax, interval=50,blit=True)
```

Comment: maybe in `update` you should to clear plot to remove previous points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize [furas' answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499219/1356000) provides a fix to your question, but here are more explanations about your problems.

First, blitting. If you want to use blitting, your `update()` function [needs to return a list of updated artists](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib-animation-funcanimation). You are returning two numpy arrays, but instead, you should `return points,`.

Your second problem about plotting keeping points of the previous time points is due to the fact that you are repetitively calling `ax.scatter()` at each iteration. Similarly to normal matplotlib behavior, if you do two  `scatter()` calls on the same axes, you end up with two sets of points.

The general recommendation for animations is to create an artist (be it a `Line2D` object using `plot()` or a `PathCollection` in the case of `scatter()`) at the initialization stage, and then *update* the properties of this artists (color, position, etc.) in the update function, without creating new artists.

Taking all of this into account, your code ends up:

```
dim = 2             #Defines the dimensionality of the system
n = 25               #Number of BOIDS
tmax = 80             #Length of sim
dmax = 5            #Distance boids can "see", determines what other boids interact with them
o = np.zeros(dim) #Origin as vector
r = np.random.rand(n,dim) #Places BOIDs randomly with co-ordinates (x,y,z) from 0 to 1. Has dimensions n and dim
v = 2*np.random.rand(n,dim)-1#Sets initial velocity of each BOID from -1 to 1 in each cardinal direction
rt = np.zeros((tmax,n,dim)) #This array contains the whole system's positions at each point in time
x = np.empty(n)
y = np.empty(n)
d = np.zeros(n)
vk = np.zeros((n,2))
vksum = np.zeros((n,2))
pltx = np.zeros((tmax,n))
plty = np.zeros((tmax,n))
"""rt[a][b][0] is the x co-ordinate of boid n=b at t=a
   rt[a][b][1] is the y co-ordiante of boid n=b at t=a
   np.linalg.norm gives the modulus of an array, check documentation for arguments"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,9))
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75') #Sets up a grid on subplot
ax.set_xlim(-50,50)
ax.set_ylim(-50,50) #Set limits for x and y axes

# initialize an empty PathCollection artist, to be updated at each iteration
points = ax.scatter([],[],c='r')    

for t in range (0,tmax):
    for i in range (0,n):
        for k in range (0,n):
            if abs(k-n)>0:
                d[k] = ((r[i][0]-r[k][0])**2+(r[i][1]-r[k][1])**2)**(1/2) #Checks distance from ith boid to each other boid
            if (d[k]-dmax)<0:   #If they are within range of the ith boid
                vk[k] = (v[i] +v[k])/((np.linalg.norm(v[i]))*np.linalg.norm(v[k]))#Aligns the velocity of ith boid toward the velocity of the kth boid
        for l in range (0,n):
            vksum[i] = vksum[i] + vk[l] #Sums the boid's velocity contributions together
        v[i] = (3/4)*v[i] + (vksum[i]/np.linalg.norm(vksum[i])) #Sets the boid's new velocity 
        r[i] = r[i] + v[i]  #Sets the boid's new position
        rt[t][i] = r[i] #Logs the position of the boid in the time array
        pltx[t][i] = r[i][0]
        plty[t][i] = r[i][1]


def init():
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[0][i][0]
        y[i] = rt[0][i][1]
    return x,y,  

def update(j):
    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[j][i][0]
        y[i] = rt[j][i][1]
    xy = np.hstack((x,y))
    points.set_offsets(xy) # update the coordinates of the PathCollection members
    return points, # return the updated artist(s) for blitting

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=tmax, interval=50,blit=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `ax.clear()` to remove previouse points (when you use `blit=False`)

```
def update(j):

    ax.clear()

    for i in range (0,n):
        x[i] = rt[j][i][0]
        y[i] = rt[j][i][1]
    points = ax.scatter(x[:], y[:], c='r')

    return x,y
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved that problem. Do you have any idea as to why I can't use blitting in the animation?

Comment: I don't know. I have only one example which works with `blit=True` and with `blit=False` but I don't know why it works - [animation sinus](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/matplotlib/animation-sinus)